# Understanding Spark CosineSimillarity output

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, cosine-similarity

I am using spark 1.6 cosine similarity (DIMSUM) algorithm.

Referring: https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/CosineSimilarity.scala

Here is what I am doing.

Input:
50k documents' text with ids in a dataframe.

Processing :

- Tokenized the texts
- Generated vectors using word2Vec
- Generated RowMatrix
- Used columnSimilarities method with threshold (DIMSUM)

Output:

- Got a coordinate matrix
- On printing out entries of this coordinate matrix I get output of
  format example: MatrixEntry(133,185,0.04106425850610451)

I do not understand what are the numbers 133 and 185. My guess was these were the document IDs/sequence number but I am not sure. Can anyone please help here?

Apologies if this question is very trivial.

Comment: Were you able to find similarity in document using the CoordinateMatrix ?

Answer (score 0):

`MatrixEntry(i, j, value)` represents a similarity between i-th and j-th column so

```
MatrixEntry(133,185,0.04106425850610451)
```

is a similarity between 133th and 185th column. These value correspond to terms not documents.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does 133rd and 185th column contain ? If the cosine value is close to 1 ,does it mean those two documents are similair

Comment: how come  i and j are columns? how do you know which documents are similar?